# IE F12 tools copy command

Tags: internet-explorer, development-environment

In Chrome DevTools, I can write `copy(someObject)` and the object will be serialized to JSON and copied to the clipboard. Is there an equivalent operation in (IE11) F12 tools? For large objects, it seems to truncate the output so I can't just copy the console contents.

Comment: IE strips out (sanitizes) scripting (eg. event handlers) when using the contextmenu copy command.... that's why you think it has been truncated. There is also security restrictions for access to the clipboard depending on the IE security zone that the current web page is mapped to.

Comment: I'm not talking about context menu copy; if you execute `someExpression` in the console and `someExpression` evaluates to some extremely long output, you'll get just the first so much of the output.

Answer (score 0):

In IE's dev tools there is no direct equivalent for `copy()`. In the console if you use the context menu's `Copy item` command it should copy the immediate children of the object in the console. The text that gets copied isn't valid JSON though.

You could create a hack wherein you use the clipboard access from the page and execute that from the console. But it's prob more work then it's worth.